# How to change the appearance of blocks located in ngFor?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor, ng-class

I have an article-map component. In it, with the help of the ngFor directive, I display brief information about the articles. I call the "article-map" component in the "feed" component. The "feed" component should have three views with different "article-map" styling. For example: the first one is a sheet, the second one is two columns, etc. How do I style the article-map component for different feed views using ngClass?

I started with the following. In article-card.component.ts I set a variable to get the parameter from the link.

```
export class ArticleCardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  typeView='default';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params)
      this.typeView=params['viewType'];
    })
  }
}
```

Now I want to write a ternary expression for ngClass that will allow different style classes to be used for feed views. Tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it will be.

```
<div [ngClass]="typeView ===  'default' ? 'css-class-1' : 'css-class-2'">
```

If you want more than one condition write a function like

html

```
<div [ngClass]="getClass()">
```

ts

```
getClass() {
    switch(this.typeView) {
        case 'default':
            return 'css-class-1';
        case 'special':
            return 'css-class-2';
        default:
            return 'css-class';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to pass a class through getClass() for other objects in html?

Comment: @ArturHaiduk ngClass works for all html elements! You're welcome!

Comment: @ArturHaiduk Good to notice that passing a function through an `ngClass` is consider being a bad practice, since the function will be triggered by every DOM changes (like scroll)

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet yeah but whats written in html cant be tested, simple functions like this will not grind your application to a halt, If your going to loop an array or find something in an array, then its a no, have been developing for many years and never had problems, I dont know what person came up with this foolish opinion

Comment: @NarenMurali For what I now, this is causing the entire component to refresh (For what I tried couple of month before), so it may, in case you have a old device & complex components structure slow the user experience, in case you want to learn a bit more about [the subject](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496#:~:text=To%20avoid%20issues%2C%20it%20is,pipe's%20input%20does%20not%20change)

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet I'd like to trust my experience, thank you for your time, Im stuck in my ways, I'm sorry

Comment: there is one but. The typeView variable must be passed to the getClass method.